# how to know the users are in the specific defined region in react

Tags: reactjs, geolocation, latitude-longitude

write the react code for the application in which application request user to get their geolocation coordinates longitude and latitude and after getting the latitude and longitude code verify the users coordinates are in the region or not and return you are inside the region or not how to approach this problem?

I try to solve this getting user location coordinates using

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(position => {
      const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
      setUserLocation({ latitude, longitude });
    });
```

after getting the coordinates i want to know how to check is this coordinates lies in the specific region and i'm unable to know how to do this